# Como faço um botão de exclusão desaparecer após ele aparecer ao ser chamado em um addEventListener do tipo click?

Tags: javascript, funções, condição

Gostaria que o botão de "remover horários" da página voltasse a não aparecer!

- A página vem com um campo já de horário
- O botão remover horário não aparece na página renderizada
- Quando o usuário clica no botão "adicionar um horário" um novo campo de horário aparece e o botão de removê-lo aparece logo ao lado do botão adicionar
- Gostaria que o botão de remover horário sumisse novamente se o usuário apagar o campo adicionando deixando apenas um horário como inicialmente na página carregada

**Trecho do html dos botões**

```
<fieldset id="schedule-items">
          <legend>Horários disponíveis
            <button type="button" id="add_time">+ Novo horário</button>
            <button type="button" id="rm-time">- Remover</button>
          </legend>
          <div class="schedule-item">
            <div class="select-block">
              <label for="weekday">Dia da semana</label>
              <select name="weekday[]" required>
```

**Bom, isso foi o que implementei em JS mas não consigo continuar a partir daí, para que o botão de remover volte a fica em modo 'hide' digamos assim, após o usuário excluir o horário adicionado**

```
document.getElementById('rm-time').style.display = 'none'

document.getElementById('add_time').addEventListener('click', showRemoveField)

function showRemoveField() {
  const getSchedules = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-item')
  const changeDisplay = document.getElementById('rm-time').style.display = ''

  if (getSchedules.length > 1) {
    return changeDisplay 
  } else {
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom graças a resposta do amigo

> @Rodrigo Carvalho de Brito
>
> > Segue resposta do mesmo:

```
$('add_time').on("click", function(){
    $('rm-time').show();
});

 $('rm-time').on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

- Para uma futura dúvida como a minha deixarei como fiz para que assim possam aparecer códigos mais bem elaborados que o meu para ajudar quem possa ter a mesma dúvida
- rm-time é o ID do botão de remover horário
- add_time é o ID do botão de adicionar um horário
- Utilizando desse código o botão adicionar horário "chama" o de remover e o mesmo some caso o usuário queira apagar um campo de horário de maneira que deixe apenas um.
- Utilizar uma condição foi necessário pois se o usuário colocasse por exemplo 3 campos de horário, usando o código direto de hide no botão rm-time o mesmo sumiria após ser clicado impedindo a remoção do segundo horário adicionado

```
$('#rm-time').hide();
$('#add_time').on("click", showRemoveField)


 function showRemoveField() {
  const showButton = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-item')

  if (showButton.length > 1) {
    return $('#rm-time').show()
  } else {
}
}

$('#rm-time').on("click", hideRemoveField)

function hideRemoveField() {
  const hideButton = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-item')
  if (hideButton.length <= 1) {
    return $('#rm-time').hide()
  } else {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está bem confusa. Se você utilizar o jQuery ficará tudo muito mais simples, simples meeeessssmo!!!

```
$('rm-time').hide();
$('add_time').on("click", function(){
    $('rm-time').show();
});
```

Para esconder o rm-time:

```
$('rm-time').on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Carvalho, obrigado pela resposta, eu melhorei a minha pergunta, na verdade a dúvida é bem simples, acho que acabei deixando bem confuso tentando explicar demais, eu estou iniciando agora nesse mundo de programação, me perdoe mas eu nem sequer conhecia o jQuery e pelo seu comentário fiquei maravilhado como foi fácil fazer com ele tudo o que fiz com o JS por si só e estou buscando mais conteúdos relacionados, mas aí no trecho que vc colocou foi exatamente o que já implementei, eu gostaria que se o usuário removesse um horário deixando apenas um, o botão de remover voltasse ao hide()

Comment: Eu reeditei a resposta. Basta ao clicar no botão de remover adicionar um evento um hide nele mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui fazer o que queria da uma olha na resposta que deixei para você entender melhor o que eu precisava ^^

Comment: Beleza! Há várias formas de se chegar ao objetivo e vc conseguiu. Ficou legível, isso que é importante para permitir manutenção futura. Se puder, de uma estudada com carinho no jQuery porque ele simplifica muita coisa de JS, contudo, o JS raiz vai te possibilitar criar um mundo de coisas legais!